# RegEx for capturing beginning of file names whilst redacting both file type and a specific set of characters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex string:

```regex
(.*?)(?=(\(\d+\))).*(\.png|\.jpg)
```

which correctly matches the following strings and stores something something something in group 1, (123) in group 2 and .extension in group 3

```
something something something (123).png
something something something (123).jpg
```

However, when I try to match the next strings I can't figure out how to get the middle part to be optional so that the following are valid matches:

```
something something something.png
something something something.jpg
```

I need the first group to store:

```
something something something
```

The second group to store:

```
(123)
```

where this can be any number of any length

and the third group to store:

```
.extension
```

where this can be either .jpg or .png

**UPDATE**

The data comes in as a single string which is scraped from the internet such as:

```regex
Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah (ID NUMBER).ext
Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah.ext

Name Blah Blah (ID NUMBER).ext
Name Blah Blah.ext

Name (Scientific Name) (ID NUMBER).ext
Name (Scientific Name).ext

Name (ID NUMBER).ext
Name.ext

Name (ID NUMBER)
Name
```

**EXAMPLES**

```
Dave (Fancy Dave) found at home (1234).png
Dave (Fancy Dave) found at pub.png

Dave found at work (1234).png
Dave found at bus stop.png

Dave (Fancy Dave) (1234).gif
Dave (Fancy Dave).jpg

Dave (1234).ext
Dave.ext

Dave (1234)
Dave
```

I need to have just the:

```
Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah
Name (Scientific Name)
Name Blah Blah
Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might be designing an expression similar to:

```
(?i)^(.*?)\s*\(\d+\)?|(.*?)(?:\.ext)?$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/PeZ9dt/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?i)^(.*?)\s*\(\d+\)?|(.*?)(?:\.ext)?$"

test_str = """

Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah (123).ext
Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah.ext
Name Blah Blah (123).ext
Name Blah Blah.ext
Name (Scientific Name) (123).ext
Name (Scientific Name).ext
Name (123).ext
Name.ext
Dave (1234)
Dave

"""
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.M)

data=[];

for each_exts in matches: 
    for each in each_exts: 
        if each!='':
            data.append(each)

print(data)
```

#### Output

```
['Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah', 'Name (Scientific Name) Blah Blah', 'Name Blah Blah', 'Name Blah Blah', 'Name (Scientific Name)', 'Name (Scientific Name)', 'Name', 'Name', 'Dave', 'Dave']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/R31Od5/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/R31Od5/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I added \s* inbetween the([^(]*?) and (\(\d+\)) to skip any whitespace after the name and the (123) or .ext

Comment: theres a small issue if the file name is: something (something).png as this would be valid as it contains (string) - something (something) something.png would be valid and so would something (something) (123).png and something (something) something (123).png

Comment: that seems closer to what I am after, do you know if there is anyway that both the (numbers) and .ext groups will be either consistent or that there is a way to get just the something's back from the groups and ignore the (123) and .ext? e.g. if its a (something) treat it as if there are no parenthesis?

Comment: Sorry and the last two cases of Dave (1234) and Dave? Other than that its exactly what I need :)

Comment: as in one sample works that is Dave (1234) but the only case that doesn't would be Dave on its own

Comment: Dave without the .ext so ext would have to be optional?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
(.*?)((\(\d+\))?).*(\.png|\.jpg)
```

It makes the (d+) group optional.

[image: here]